# HTML Navigation Hover

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, navigation, onhover

This is my nav bar with a drop down menu below some. Book goes below Departments, I have a lot more but this is an example. When I hover over more options, it loses focus on the nav bar and shows the on hover discription for an image. how do i stop this?

```
<div class="NavBar">
        <div align="center">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Pop-Shopping Homepage Page.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Pop-Shopping Homepage Page.html">Departments</a>
                    <ul class="MiniNavBar">
                        <li><a href="Pop-Shopping Homepage Page.html">Books</a></li>
<li><a href="Pop-Shopping Homepage Page.html">Books</a></li>
<li><a href="Pop-Shopping Homepage Page.html">Books</a></li>
<li><a href="Pop-Shopping Homepage Page.html">Books</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li><a href="Pop-Shopping Homepage Page.html">Top Brands</a></li>
                <li><a href="Pop-Shopping Homepage Page.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="Pop-Shopping Homepage Page.html">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS

```
.NavBar{
    background-color: #C10000;
    height: auto;
    width: 430px;
    border: thin solid #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 8px;
 }

.MiniNavBar{
    width: 97px;
}

.NavBar ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.NavBar ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.NavBar ul {
    padding: 2px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 15px; 
}

.NavBar ul li {
    float: left;
}

.NavBar ul li:hover {
    background-color: #C10000;
    color: #FFDD00;
}

.NavBar ul li:hover a {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFDD00;
}

.NavBar ul li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background-color: #C10000;
    color: #FFDD00;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.NavBar ul ul {
    position: absolute; 
}

.NavBar ul ul li {
    float: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.NavBar ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    background-color: #C10000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}   

.NavBar ul ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #C10000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.NavBar ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    top:0;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, we are known for our crystal ball debugging but this question is just next level, please replicate your problem and only add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: @BasementKeyboardHero is that better?

Comment: @Rajan, consider pasting your code into a demo at http://jsfiddle.net. BKH, your abuse of the comma is nearly as offensive as a vague question. ;-)

Comment: @BasementKeyboardHero Haha

Comment: I fiddled your code and I don't see what your issue is. Could you explain a bit more what you want to be resolved/or what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Jason ok. So when you hover over departments tab on the navigation  bar more options appear. On my whole code i have image's which when you hover over them their caption appear. So when you scroll over the navigation bar and reach an image the hover won't allow you to go past the image and instead display the caption. So you can't view any option of the drop down part of the navigation bar that go past the images. Is that making sense??

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was anyway to stop that from happening. Like in the css tell when you hover over the navigation bar stop the hover on the images